# ADO.NET Entity Data Model is not showing in Visual studio 2012 express

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I tried the solutions those are in the internet for this problem but none of them working.
When I click on Model and add new item no ADO.NET Entity Data Model  option is showing

I observed one solution like try devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs this but its showing

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs
'devenv.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Where is your visual studio installed? devenv.exe is the executable that launches Visual studio. The command you're trying to run must be run from the folder that contains your visual studio express installation. For example, Visual Studio 2010 might be under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

Comment: yeah not not present in that folder

Comment: this is the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2v3gc0k7ru9qxk/adomissing.JPG?dl=0

Comment: You can find where your devenv.exe is located by checking the target on the visual studio application [right-click --> properties --> target]. Next, navigate to that folder on your terminal [command prompt] and run your command as above